# How do I download an embedded flash game from a site?

Tags: super-mario-63

I would like to play [Super Mario 63](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/498969) on my work laptop, but not in a browser. I have only found the game embedded on a site. How can I download it?

Comment: What is Super Mario 63? Edit: Found it: http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/498969 (Flash game on New Grounds). So is the question then, "How can I play flash games on a machine I'm not allowed to install flash?"

Comment: No idea, but @Prashant apparently means 63 and not 64 (which is why I rolled back your edit @Andy). *Edit: Oh, perhaps a new question should be asked with that title, as the answers are completely irrelevant to it @Raven*

Comment: What OS is the computer in question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generalize: there are flash games you are allowed to download and distribute and there are flash games which are not allowed to download and distribute,

Companies that allow you to make a login and download flash games to play them locally and/or copy them to your own site (i have downloaded about 45.000 flash games) among others:

- mochi: http://www.mochigames.com/search/?q=super+mario
- http://www.heyzap.com/games?q=mario&x=0&y=0

If you want to have a lot of options around this like auto downloading etc..., then install XAMP, WordPress and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/myarcadeblog/ and you can run this semi automatically in other words: it acts as a GUI for all of this. 
Notice that XAMP installs a local webserver that enables you to play the games on your localhost.

Answer (score 6):

**It is not possible to run flash games without installing flash.**

Comment: Portable n64, not sure how practical this project is, heh: http://benheck.com/n64-portable

Comment: i know this, i already play game on laptop over internet so I have the flash. How i download game not as pirate?

Comment: You can fish around the page's data to find the exact file the .swf is, and download it (most popular browsers have this feature). Then, opening the local file in your browser will let you play it offline. I don't know where this stands on the piracy scale, though.

Comment: I think this question is the victim of overzealous editing, as I now have no idea what was originally intended to be asked.

Comment: Seeing as downloading the swf and running it locally breaks the ads, I think you can safely call that piracy.

Answer (score 1):

*Super Mario 63* can be downloaded as a standalone executable (not sure if it need Flash) from Runouw's (the creator's) site. However, the site seems to be low on bandwidth right now, so I can't give exact instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the [Flash Player Projector](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) for your platform. Depending on the installer, there might not be a way to get around installing, especially on Windows. Mac OS X installer packages can be manually extracted, so no big deal there. Windows installers are trickier and often do registry updates (the big deal breaker).

If the machine in question is a Windows machine, try installing the Flash Projector on a Windows computer you admin and then copy the Projector application to the other computer and see if that works.